# Content overflowing flex item despite overflow property

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I have a pretty simple page setup in the following manner using flexboxes:

[image]

The blue `div` is supposed to make up 25% in height and the violet `div` 75%. In case there are too many lines in the blue `div`, it should stay the same size an show a scrollbar. This works for a few lines, but breaks at some point and the blue `div` overflows and grows into the violet one. I'm new to flexboxes, so I don't really understand why this is happening. Would I be better off not using flexboxes? Thankful for any hints or pointer at this point.

This is the code I use (run in full page):

```js
function lines(noLines) {
  var text = "line</br>".repeat(noLines);
  document.getElementById("lower").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#static1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

#static2 {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

#left {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#right {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#upper {
  flex: 3 0;
  background-color: violet;
}

#lower {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div id="static1">Some static div</div>
  <div id="static2">Another static div. Flexbox below fills rest of remaining screen.</div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="left">
      Left part, fixed width in percentage.</br>
      Click to enter lines into the bottom right:</br>
      <button onclick=lines(20)>Few Lines</button>
      <button onclick=lines(200)>Many Lines</button>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <div id="upper">Flexbox with flex=3.</div>
      <div id="lower">Flexbox with flex=1.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property to work properly, the container needs an actual height or max-height. Flex heights (you have `flex: 1` on `.content`) won't cut it.

> In order for `overflow` to have an effect, the block-level container
> must have either a set height (`height` or `max-height`) or
> `white-space` set to `nowrap`. ~ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Since you already know the height of the primary container (`100vh`) and the first two rows (`30px` and `40px`), the rest is simple using the `calc()` function.

```js
function lines(noLines) {
  var text = "line</br>".repeat(noLines);
  document.getElementById("lower").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;  /* adjustment */
}

#static1 {
  flex-shrink: 0;  /* disable shrinking */
  height: 30px;
  /* width: 100%; */
  background-color: red;
}

#static2 {
  flex-shrink: 0;  /* disable shrinking */
  height: 40px;
  /* width: 100%; */
  background-color: orange;
}

#content {
  height: calc(100vh - 70px); /* new */
  display: flex;
  /* flex: 1; */ /* may work in some browsers, but not reliable */
}

#left {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#right {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#upper {
  flex: 3 0;
  background-color: violet;
}

#lower {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: aqua; /* adjusted for illustration */
  overflow: auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0; /* new; override browser default  */
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div id="static1">Some static div</div>
  <div id="static2">Another static div. Flexbox below fills rest of remaining screen.</div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="left">
      Left part, fixed width in percentage.<br> Click to enter lines into the bottom right:<br>
      <button onclick=lines(20)>Few Lines</button>
      <button onclick=lines(200)>Many Lines</button>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <div id="upper">Flexbox with flex=3.</div>
      <div id="lower">Flexbox with flex=1.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qvmh26zj/)

Comment: I tried avoiding explicitly calculating the container height with hard-coded values or via JavaScript and tried relying on HTML and CSS only. But for the time being this is probably what I'm going with, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you mean, but If I'm wrong, apologies. The problem I can see lies in the way you are using `flex: 1` & `flex: 3` to define the proportions of the right column, without specifying to what height their parent container has, i.e. `#right` has no height, so the box can always expand as it gets more filled with content.

Please try this, I hope this works and if I can answer anything else, just ask please.

The only thing I changed was your CSS and added `max-height: calc(100vh - 70px);` to the `#right` div. And changed `overflow: auto;` to `overflow-y: scroll;`

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  
}

#static1 {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

#static2 {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

#left {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#right {
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 70px);
}

#upper {
  flex: 3;
  height: 75%;
  background-color: violet;
}

#lower {
  flex: 1;
  height: 25%;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the top part of CSS to this:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```